# Teradata OUTER Apply

Tags: teradata, apply, outer-join

I'm converting a MS SQL code to Teradata and had bump up an OUTER APPLY that has no Teradata equivalent. So I searched online and they said that it's basically a LEFT OUTER JOIN but it lets you efficiently use subqueries in it.
I tried to convert it but I got a different result. 
Below are the codes

**SQL**

```
select 
    s.*,
    s2.NStartDate,
    s2.NextL 
from tDates s
outer apply (
        select 
        MIN(s2.StartDate)   NStartDate,
        CAST(MIN(CAST(s2.LFL as int)) as bit) NextL
        from tDates s2
        where
            s2.StoreNo = s.StoreNo
        and s2.StartDate > s.StartDate 
        and s2.LFL = case s.LFL when 0 then 1 else 0 end
    ) s2
```

**TERADATA**

```
SELECT
        s.*,
        s2.NStartDate, 
        s2.NextL
  FROM tDates s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT
                s2.StoreNo, 
                MIN(s2.StartDate) AS NStartDate, 
                CAST(MIN(CAST(s2.LFL AS  INTEGER)) AS  BYTEINT) AS NextL
            FROM tDates s2
            GROUP BY 
                s2.StoreNo
        ) s2
    ON s2.StoreNo = s.StoreNo
    AND s2.NStartDate > s.StartDate
    AND s2.NextL = CASE s.LFL WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Outer Apply:
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o
    |StoreN|  SCode  | NStartDate   | NextL |
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o
    |   1  |   A     | 2016-01-13   |  10   |
    |   1  |   A     | 2016-01-12   |  20   |
    |   2  |   B     | 2016-01-08   |  40   |
    |   2  |   B     | 2016-01-06   |  30   |
    |   3  |   C     |   NULL       |  NULL |
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o

Left Outer Join:
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o
    |StoreN|  SCode  | NStartDate   | NextL |
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o
    |   1  |   A     | 2016-01-13   |  10   |
    |   1  |   A     | 2016-01-12   |  20   |
    |   2  |   B     |   NULL       |  NULL |
    |   3  |   C     |   NULL       |  NULL |
    o------o---------o--------------o-------o
```

Is there something wrong with my conversion? Or had miss something?

Thanks

Comment: Cab you show some data and expected result? IMHO there's no need for Outer Apply, should be a task for an Analytic Function like `FIRST_VALUE`

Comment: @dnoeth Hello, I don't know how to post picture here in comment but I'll explain. Same record counts, same data on the left side columns BUT some of the data on the right side of the columns are showing NULL (on Teradata). I still don't know either why the original code used Outer Apply.

Comment: Don't post pictures in comments, edit your query and add readable data including expected result and explanation of the applied logic. Outer Apply is only similar to an Outer Join, but not exactly the same (otherwise you wouldn't need it)

Comment: Adding some base rows would be helpful, I don't get the `CAST(MIN(CAST(s2.LFL as int)) as bit)` part (returns `FALSE` for `LFL=0` and `TRUE` otherwise?), what's the datatype of `LFL`?

Comment: the datatype for LFL is BYTEINT (bit for SQL). The original code is really redundant but have to follow as well.

Comment: SQL Server's `BIT` only stores 0/1 (fales/true), how can your result show other values for `NextL`?

Comment: I tried to implement the same syntax (left outer join) on SQL and was getting the same with Teradata. I think there is an additional feature of Outer Apply that Left outer join can't, not sure though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OUTER APPLY` is Microsoft's implementation of Standard SQL's `LATERAL JOIN`, it's a kind of Correlated Join. When it's returning single rows (like your `MIN`) it can be replaced by Correlated Scalar Subqueries, one for each column, but with performance will be bad.

As you access the same table twice the best rewrite will be based on Analytic Functions, although the `s2.LFL = case s.LFL when 0 then 1 else 0 end` is a bit tricky:

```
SELECT 
   s.*,
   CASE
      WHEN LFL=0 
           -- only check LFL 1 for the minimum date
      THEN Min(CASE WHEN LFL = 1 THEN StartDate END)
           Over (PARTITION BY StoreNo
                 ORDER BY StartDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND Unbounded Following)
      ELSE -- only check LFL 0 for the minimum date
           Min(CASE WHEN LFL = 0 THEN StartDate END)
           Over (PARTITION BY StoreNo
                 ORDER BY StartDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND Unbounded Following)
   END AS NStartDate,

   -- repeated logic, one for each column
   -- returns 0/1/NULL -> doesn't match your result set
   CASE
      WHEN LFL=0
      THEN Min(CASE WHEN LFL = 1 THEN LFL END)
           Over (PARTITION BY StoreNo
                 ORDER BY StartDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND Unbounded Following)
      ELSE Min(CASE WHEN LFL = 0 THEN LFL END)
           Over (PARTITION BY StoreNo
                 ORDER BY StartDate
                 ROWS BETWEEN 1 Following AND Unbounded Following)
    END AS NextL
FROM tDates s
```

This should result in a single STATS-step in Explain.

Based on your comments `LFL` is a `bit` datatype (0/1, TRUE/FALSE), thus `CAST(MIN(CAST(s2.LFL as int)) as bit)` is totally useless and doesn't match your result set with `NextL` values like 10.